# Guest additions 'unable to locate program' Kali Linux 2.0

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux

**Problem:** When trying to install guest additions in Kali linux the following error occurs.

> Oops! There was a problem running this software. Unable to locate program

This occurred after a fresh install of Kali Linux 2.0 in Virtual Box 4.3.32

**Action taken to get this error:**

```
Virtualbox -> Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD image
```

then from Kali Linux GUI the message

> "VBOXADDITIONS_4.3.32_103443" contains software intended to be automatically started. Would you like to run it?

Select **run** and the error occurs

How to solve this problem? What is the cause?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The question is a bit old, but deserves an answer to the root cause of the error, not a work-around.

The root cause of your issue is in `/etc/fstab`.  If yours looks anything like mine, the mount options for `/dev/sr0` are probably `user,noauto`.  The `user` option automatically implies `noexec` which strips executable bits off all binary files on the mounted file system.

You simply need to add the `exec` option to your mount statement in `/etc/fstab`

from:

```
/dev/sr0    /media/cdrom0    udf,iso9660    user,noauto         0    0
```

to:

```
/dev/sr0    /media/cdrom0    udf,iso9660    user,noauto,exec    0    0
```

This will allow you to execute binaries from optical media.

Cheers,

Rich

Comment: I had to do this and also install `build-essential` plus the headers, `linux-headers-$(uname -r)`; or what the name is on your distro.

Comment: I had the same problem with a Debian VM, and this solved it! Thanks.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to get this to work on a Debian 10.8 Linux guest under VirtualBox. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

I don't know exactly what the cause is but it seems that perhaps it is a permission issue...(not exactly sure)

You can get around this problem by opening up `terminal` and calling

`sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`

**Refernce:** https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=58799

Comment: I've just run the following since there is no file named "VBoxLinuxAdditions.run" in my case: sudo sh /media/cdrom/autorun.sh

Comment: /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run doesn't have permission by default. Change permission it will show in tab press

Answer (score -1):

Copy the installation files to a writable directory & run the setup from there.

Comment: This answer is a bit carelessly written. I doubt that the error is fixed by your suggestion.