# How to install guest additions on Kali Linux 4.15.0

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox

I've installed the latest version of Kali Linux using virtualbox but I can't install guest additions, I found this  [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239973/guest-additions-unable-to-locate-program-kali-linux-2-0).

After `uname -r` command I have in my terminal:

```
4.15.0-kali2-amd64
```

And when I try to install linux-headers executing `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` command I have the following errors:

```
Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.15.0-kali2-amd64
Couldn't find any package by global 'linux-headers-4.15.0-kali2-amd64'
Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.15.0-kali2-amd64'
```

For comparison I've installed Ubuntu on Virtualbox and it is working fine.

Please tell me what can I do in this case?

Comment: Kudos on that edit @Rui, I much prefer that over linking to the usual Q&A ;-)

Comment: @StephenKitt I have my honest doubts this question seen from a broader angle has not been asked before. However, it is a waste to close a well written question with a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your kernel is out-of-date, and the corresponding kernel header packages are no longer available. You need to upgrade your system:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
```

then reboot your VM. This should give you [the current kernel](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/linux), 4.17.0-kali3 as I write this, and allow you to install the corresponding header packages.

To install the guest additions then, [run the following command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/286934/86440):

```
apt install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-x11 linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: I don't know how and why but my /etc/apt/sources.list file was empty i just added "Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.15.0-kali2-amd64'" into this file and followed your steps in your answer and it is working fine for me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Stephen,  We are having multiple instances of people having the `sources.list` empty. It might be more than clueless users, or a statistic anomaly, something is wrong. Which in turns makes that duplicatte having more sense where applicable.

Comment: Yes, I think there are several (real) dupes for this question...

Answer (score 0):

When you run apt update and the kernel getting updated to a newer version. The command `uname -r` may takes the current older kernel version.

This mismatches between the updated kernel version and the old version the reason why it fails.

So to test: Do not update

1. apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
2. do not install the new headers
3. run update and upgrade
4. rerun apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
5. error
6. reboot
7. rerun apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
8. works..

Comment: Welcome, The question is how to install the guest addition, not the `linux-headers`.

Comment: It does seem like the *title* of the question is aimed at installing the guest additions, but the question (confusingly) lands at asking how to get past the "unable to locate ... linux-headers..." issue.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Already mentioned on the accepted answer , upgrading the package , rebooting , installing the kernel headers and the guest additions.

Comment: That it does and I was providing feedback on why it fails. Sure it was the accepted answer but I wanted to provide additional information on WHY it actually fails.

Don't understand the downvoting tbh.